# Java IO File not found exception

Tags: java, android, urlconnection

I developed a servlet and i'm trying to access it through an android application. Here is the important part from my async class. 'params[0]' is the url passed in as a parameter

```
URL url;
BufferedReader reader = null;
String s = "";
try {
    url = new URL(params[0]);
    URLConnection con = url.openConnection();
      reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
      con.getInputStream()));
    String line = "";
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        s = s + line;
    }
} catch (MalformedURLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

This works most of the times. But sometimes, i get a java.io.FileNotFoundException
When i take the same url and try it in a browser it works, but from my application it doesn't work no matter how many times i try it. Here is my logcat:

```
05-14 19:35:51.852: W/System.err(767): java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://192.168.10.105:8080/CarpoolServer/EditProfileServlet?name=anna&yob=1977&gender=Female&major=Architecture&uni=N/A&occupation=Software Development&hobby1=Basketball&hobby2=Reading&hobby3=Football&email=jad_naoum%40hotmail.com&phone=70202018&from11=Beirut&from12=Beirut&from13=Mousseitbeh&to11=Beirut&to12=Beirut&to13=Mazraa&days1=SAT&time_from1=3:21AM&time_to1=4:21PM&car=true
05-14 19:35:51.852: W/System.err(767):  at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:186)
05-14 19:35:51.852: W/System.err(767):  at com.jad.carpooling.EditProfile$Async.doInBackground(EditProfile.java:416)
05-14 19:35:51.862: W/System.err(767):  at com.jad.carpooling.EditProfile$Async.doInBackground(EditProfile.java:1)
05-14 19:35:51.862: W/System.err(767):  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
05-14 19:35:51.862: W/System.err(767):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
05-14 19:35:51.862: W/System.err(767):  at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
05-14 19:35:51.862: W/System.err(767):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
05-14 19:35:51.872: W/System.err(767):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
05-14 19:35:51.872: W/System.err(767):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

Any ideas?

---

---

I figured it out. It seems that I didn't encode the URL properly. There is a space in the URL. When I encoded it, it worked.
Thanks for the help

Comment: I guess the URL is an internal URL. Are you sure, that the App doesn't try to connect via mobile network? That would mean, that the File doesn't exist, because the android device is not in your wireless network.

Comment: You say: (**1**) "*This works most of the times.*" and then (**2**) "*but from my application it doesn't work no matter how many times I try it.*"  Seems self-contradictory to me.

Comment: "This works most of the times, BUT SOMETIMES i get an exception"
When i get the exception, it doesn't work anymore

Comment: @MalaKa it has worked using the same URL. The error occurs sometimes

Comment: My thought was, that WLAN is active on the Android device. And normally it connects via the WLAN to the internet. But if it happens, that the device uses the mobile network, the IP `192.168.10.105` is unavailable. That would explain, why the error only occurs sometimes - it only occurs when the device tries to connect via mobile network.

Comment: Please check my edit. The url contained a space that's why it didn't work

Answer (score 1):

You have to replace all spaces with %20
So here is code for replacing space.

```
strUrl = strUrl.replace(" ", "%20");
```

Comment: strUrl = strUrl.replace(" ", "%20");